# 'Could not find valid value for id',' is not of the type Positive Errors', unable to find root cause

Tags: civievent, civimember, contacts, webform-civicrm, payment-processor

I've been trying to figure out the root cause of this error for a while and I haven't really made much progress. There is a number of threads which people in different situations but all avenues didn't seem to help.

I seem to get the could not find valid venue for ID errors for both the registration process and event signups.  At first I thought it an issue with the registration process only but then noticed it was happening for events also.  I was then also able to trigger the issue ( only once mind )  whilst adding a contact manually in Civicrm.

It seems that when it attempts to retrieve the ID it cannot find a value.

The site is currently using the latest version of Drupal, Latest civicrm web form integration module (use for membership signups) and civi 5.13.4 although this issue has persisted across multiple versions.

I've reviewed the settings files, base URLs, all sorts but can't figure out why there isn't an ID provided.

Does anyone have any fresh ideas of what I can check?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

[image]

```
Sep 19 06:14:12  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(385): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(121): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(50): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo), TRUE)
#3 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)
#4 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#5 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#6 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#7 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "info")
#8 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#9 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}
```

```
Sep 19 00:11:40  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(385): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(571): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("id (value: 509'A=0) is not of the type Positive")
#2 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(108): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("509'A=0", "Positive", TRUE, "id")
#3 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(50): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo), TRUE)
#4 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)
#5 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#6 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#7 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#8 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "info")
#9 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#10 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#11 {main}
```

```
 [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(385): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(121): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Event/StateMachine/Registration.php(52): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)
#3 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Event/Controller/Registration.php(47): CRM_Event_StateMachine_Registration->__construct(Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)
#4 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(306): CRM_Event_Controller_Registration->__construct("Event Registration", TRUE, "null", NULL, "false")
#5 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#6 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#7 /home/myciviwebsite/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#8 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "register")
#9 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#10 /home/myciviwebsite/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#11 {main}
```

Comment: This line is interesting: `fatal("id (value: 509'A=0) is not of the type Positive")`. Any ideas where the id would be such a weird value? `509'A=0`

Comment: Not yet.  Only thing I was thinking could it be because it's running in PHP56? Other than that I'm a bit stumped at the moment!

Comment: The pasted code from the "run()" function seems to throw an error when the event info page does not have an id specified. It does make sense as there is no point of loading this page without an id. But look out if you can replicate this issue after returning from the payment processor site, i.e, after the payment process is completed and you end up on the thankyou page with a qfkey and no id. In this case, the page should load as the id is in the session instead of the URL. So I think this might replicate only if the id is removed from the session due to some reason during the process.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion That's helpful thanks.  I think it could be relating to session issues and potentially calling an incorrect URL ( and then redirecting ).  I've found some situations where it's doesn't think a user has a session. As the above when someone was simply just adding a contact in CiviCRM.

Comment: I am also running into this issue. Fortunately the event registration works, but it is really bad for users of our website.